# Relational Awareness

Tags: c#, matrix, orm, relation

I'm encountering an issue whilst trying to create an arrangement of items. I'm creating a game which takes place on a board which is composed of items called Terrain. Each Terrain on the board is its own unique item with properties and relations specific to itself. An important part of the Terrain generation requires each space to be able to refer to its adjacent tiles and I also foresee the eventual need for such implementation later as well so I'd like to overcome it now.

The main issue I am encountering is I have no idea how to make each member of the matrix aware of each other and themselves in relation to the entire thing. For some insight on how it works, the design is dual layered.

There is first a general collection which contains all the members. Each member is contained in its own generic item which contains both the raw data as well as the position of the item in the collection.

The most important criteria is that I can  not have the objects being related by searching through the large collection. I need to have each item contain a reference to all its relevant neighbors, be able to edit its neighbors from that reference, and avoid all recursion in the updating of those items.

I am essentially attempting to create something almost identical to a one to one relationship from a database so that it only exists in one place but is accessible from its fellow members which are like records in the database analogy.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, each tile needs to be aware of and able to reference the adjacent tiles in the matrix. The first solution that comes to mind is using pointers, but as this is c# it's probably better to stick to safe methods.

My solution to this problem would be to include in the constructor for the type `Terrain` an argument for an array of `Terrain`s, as well as an integer argument with the position of that particular element in the array.

If you do this, then the `Terrain` can get the adjacent items from the array relative to its own position; the item to the right will be its position + 1, of course, and the element to the left would be its position - 1.
The element above would be the position minus the width of the gameboard, and the element below would be the position plus the width of the gameboard.

Comment: Or is this not a valid solution? You said it needs to not search through the collection, but I'm not sure if you meant this or something else...

Comment: No, this is an unfortunately not a valid solution because while each member of the matrix is aware of its own position, it is irrelevant its relative position to other items because that is how it must be referenced manually. 
What you're describing doesn't solve that particular facet of the issue UNLESS each tile contains all the other tiles but then the update of each leads to the recursive updating problem. Its kid of like the set of all sets that doesn't contain itself. Anytime you update it to not include itself, it them must be update to include itself and the stack will never resolve